# Videos will not play in any browser from any source, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome, browser, video-streaming

I have a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop,

And a few days ago videos stopped playing in any browser.  I tried Chrome and Chromium and Firefox, I tried YouTube and Vimeo and Udemy videos.

In all cases the video appears to load/buffer, but it won't play.  I can seek through the video and see any frame, but they won't play!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Do you get any errors if you launch the browser in question from the command line? The fact that you can seek through the video and see individual frames indicates to me that the appropriate codecs are installed. This question is unclear (at least to me) as it raises a number of questions as is. What versions of Chrome, Chromium and Firefox did you try? Did you try purging and reinstalling the affected browsers? Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by bluetooth speaker. I turn off my speaker then all videos werer playable on any browser. It's a connection issue.